# GameMaker 2D Visibility

Tags: 2d, visibility, raycasting, game-maker-language

I would like to implement in GameMaker exactly the same thing as in this article: http://www.redblobgames.com/articles/visibility/.

The code for it is available there in different languages, but I can't figure out how to effectively port it to GML. Every raycasting solution I tried leads to fps completely dying.

Could someone with more knowledge than me help ?

Answer (score 3):

i have encountered this problem too, it mainly stems from the gamemakers execution speed.
check out the gm tech blog post on this [here](http://www.yoyogames.com/blog/99).

Also, this will probably work best as a shader as they run faster than object step events.

good luck!

Comment: I actually found this brilliant and completely free engine called SmartLight: http://cbna.forumactif.com/t10023-cbna-smartlight-moteur-de-lumiere. The documentation is in French but you can find a translation on the old GameMaker forums.